# Full width footer issue

Tags: width, fixed-width, css

At the moment a site I am working on ([4beaufort.co.uk](http://4beaufort.co.uk/)) has a footer (#page-bottom) with the css properties:

```
#page-bottom {
width:100%;
margin-top:3%;
margin-left:0%;
margin-right:0%;
margin-bottom:0%;
position:absolute;}
```

I had to make the div position absolute so to force it to fit across 100% of the screen as before, for some reason I have not been able to work out, it only stretched to about 98% of the screen leaving a small gap on the right hand side. This is fine, but it's not a great solution as it is causing all content above the footer to scroll slightly horizontally?

Can anyone work out where I am going wrong?

Have looked for ages throughout the style sheet to see if I've mis-set a container etc. Have set all containers to 100% width etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think u have used 100% width and set padding for the same class or id in your stylesheet. thats not with `#page-bottom` . check all the id's and classes inside the page. its something with the `#page` in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position:absolute` and use `float:left`. That's it!